# How to split special charaters and index every special characters using lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, lucene

If the given text is "$("#debug_threads")." i need to index the tokens as "$","(", ""","#","debug","_","threads,""",")", ".". i have tried using a token filter but could not accomplish it.

Comment: You need a tokenizer like pattern tokenizer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html

Comment: I have tried pattern tokeniser but i dont know how to index the delimiter. For example :
i executed the following
`PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "(\\w|_|\\s)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`
and `POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "$(\"#debug_threads\") "
}`
but the special characters are not indexed.

Comment: There is a group parameter in pattern tokenizer which controls what tokens are emitted, you would have to dig into source code to see if it will let you emit splits + split characters as I don't see a full explanation of the parameter values in the docs